# Solving equation to find capacitance for minimum impedance

Tags: equation-solving

Trying to solve this

```
z1 := -I/(ω*c2) + I*ω*l1 + r1

z2 := -I/(ω*c1)

z := (z1*z2)/(z1 + z2)

zr := Simplify[
  Re[z], {c1, c2, l1, r1, ω} ∈ 
    Reals && {c1, c2, l1, r1, ω} > 0]

zd := D[zr, c2]


Solve[{zd == 0, l1 == 17.534*10^-3, r1 == 4.6, 
  c1 == 18.1*10^-9, ω == 20*10^3, c2 ∈ Reals}, c2]
```

It just hangs calculating.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, post code as code so that it can be copied...

Comment: Sorry, posted as code now.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the optimal way but this worked for me (ignore the addition of 2 pi, this is not important)

I made 2 changes:

1. Used `ComplexExpand` to get the real part
2. Used `Simplify` before `Solve` (just using `Solve` directly gave no solutions)

   ```
   z1 := -I/(ω*c2) + I*ω*l1 + r1

   z2 := -I/(ω*c1)

   z := (z1*z2)/(z1 + z2)

   zr := ComplexExpand[Re[z]]

   zd := D[zr, c2]

   ims := Simplify[zd, {l1 == 17.534*10^-3, r1 == 4.6, 
     c1 == 18.1*10^-9, ω == 2*π*20*10^3}]

   Solve[{ims == 0, c2 > 0}, c2]
   ```

Comment: The addition of the `2 Pi` is important since there is no solution with the lower value of ω.

Comment: Hm, Indeed, I've not tried without 2 pi, thanks